# golang reading XML memory leak?

Tags: xml, memory-leaks, go, profiling

We've been decoding a lot of XML lately using golang and `encoding/xml`. We noticed that, after quite a few files, our boxes run out of memory, start swapping, and generally die an unhappy death. So we made a test program. Here it is:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"
)

// this XML is for reading AWS SQS messages
type message struct {
    Body          []string `xml:"ReceiveMessageResult>Message>Body"`
    ReceiptHandle []string `xml:"ReceiveMessageResult>Message>ReceiptHandle"`
}

func main() {
    var m message

    readTicker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Millisecond)

    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.xml")

    for {
        select {
        case <-readTicker.C:
            err = xml.Unmarshal(body, &m)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err.Error())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All it does is repeatedly decode an XML file over and over again. Our boxes show the same symptom: the memory usage of the binary grows without bound, until the box starts swapping.

We also added in some profiling code, which fires after 20s into the above script, and got the following from `pprof`'s `top100`:

```
(pprof) top100
Total: 56.0 MB
    55.0  98.2%  98.2%     55.0  98.2% encoding/xml.copyValue
     1.0   1.8% 100.0%      1.0   1.8% cnew
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.9% bytes.(*Buffer).WriteByte
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.9% bytes.(*Buffer).grow
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.5   0.9% bytes.makeSlice
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%     55.5  99.1% encoding/xml.(*Decoder).Decode
...
```

Running this later on, before the box runs out of memory, yields a higher total but pretty much the same percentages. Can anyone help us out? What are we missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen that odd loop several times.  Not sure where it comes from, but there's way too much code there.  Try this:  http://play.golang.org/p/GFkmfn_CYV (also fixed your memory issue)

Comment: thanks! I'd not seen `range ticker` before!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try printing out your message each time. It will continue to append the fields onto the original struct.

You need to reset the message with `m = message{}` after you do what you need to do with it, to clear it out, otherwise it will continue to grow.

Comment: Great catch! I wonder if it's a bug or the desired behavior. Looks to me like a bug.

Comment: No, it's desired behavior. According to the documentation: "Unmarshal maps an XML element to a slice by extending the length of the slice and mapping the element to the newly created value."

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this yet but did you tried to unmarshal the XML into a new variable every time you do it?

As far as I see you are doing it in a pointer which might create some issues with the memory.

But of course, I might be totally wrong.